# Why does Elixir Plug compile plugs into AST using macro?

Tags: elixir, plug

As the code https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/v1.5.0/lib/plug/builder.ex#L183 shows, plugs definition will be compiled to AST at macro expansion phase. But why? Why not just keep the plugs definition and use `Enum.reduce_while` or recursion to call plugs one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons I can think of:

1. Performance. Consider these two snippets that do the same thing but one does it using compiled function calls and the other uses `Enum.reduce` and `apply`:

   ```
   defmodule A do
     def add1(x), do: x + 1
     def sub1(x), do: x - 1

     def compiled(x) do
       x
       |> add1()
       |> sub1()
       |> add1()
       |> sub1()
       |> add1()
       |> sub1()
       |> add1()
       |> sub1()
     end

     @pipeline [
       {A, :add1},
       {A, :sub1},
       {A, :add1},
       {A, :sub1},
       {A, :add1},
       {A, :sub1},
       {A, :add1},
       {A, :sub1}
     ]
     def runtime(x) do
       Enum.reduce(@pipeline, x, fn {module, function}, acc ->
         apply(module, function, [acc])
       end)
     end
   end
   ```

   A simple benchmark shows that the runtime implementation is 5 times slower.

   ```
   IO.inspect(
     :timer.tc(fn ->
       for _ <- 1..1_000_000, do: A.compiled(123)
       :ok
     end)
     |> elem(0)
   )

   IO.inspect(
     :timer.tc(fn ->
       for _ <- 1..1_000_000, do: A.runtime(123)
       :ok
     end)
     |> elem(0)
   )
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   82800
   433198
   ```
2. Catching bugs at compile time. If you pass a module to `plug` that doesn't implement `call/2`, you get an error at compile time instead of a runtime error you'd normally get if you do everything at runtime.